# Add Custom Tab in office 365 web Word project

Tags: javascript, html, xml, office365, ribbonx

I am trying add a custom tab in office 365 Word in the ribbon. There are countless examples of how to do this in VSTO that I can find, but no code example of this in Office 365 AddIn web project.

Closest thing I found is this documentation below. This is also lacking any proper coding sample. Also, this was writting in July 2022.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/customtab?view=powerpoint-js-preview

From this link below, I can tell that adding a tab is allowed in Office 365, but the coding samples are from 6 to 7 years ago.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands

There is also this video tutorial and similar ones like this - but this doesn't show adding new tab.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWw-fJ7eldU

There are samples that show how to make Task Pane project. But not for add a custom tab in the ribbon and then add a menu inside it.

Am I missing something? Does office 365 web project allow for adding custom tab? If so, can someone point me to a sample coding project or a video tutorial that shows this?

Answer (score 0):

The ribbon UI extensibility features in web add-ins are still limited comparing to Office COM add-ins, but with a time MS adds features such as contextual tabs support, position on the ribbon (preview), enabled/disabled state, integration of built-in controls. Read more about all that features in the [Add-in commands for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) article.

There are two types of add-in commands, based on the kind of action that the command triggers.

1. Task pane commands: The button or menu item opens the add-in's task pane. You add this kind of add-in command with markup in the manifest. The "code behind" the command is provided by Office.
2. Function commands: The button or menu item runs any arbitrary JavaScript. The code almost always calls APIs in the Office JavaScript Library, but it doesn't have to. This type of add-in typically displays no UI other than the button or menu item itself. Note the following about function commands:

   - The function that is triggered can call the displayDialogAsync method to show a dialog, which is a good way to display an error, show progress, or prompt for input from the user. If the add-in is configured to use a shared runtime, the function can also call the showAsTaskpane method.
   - The runtime in which the function command runs is a full browser-based runtime. It can render HTML and call out to the Internet to send or get data.

Use `VersionOverrides` in your manifest to define add-in commands for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word. Add-in commands provide an easy way to customize the default Office user interface (UI) with specified UI elements that perform actions. See [Create add-in commands in your manifest for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands).

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. I saw both these and when I tried samples from it I started seeing project errors. Hence was looking for a coding sample that is not standard documentation. It is surprising that there is not a single one, apparently.

Comment: There are a lot of samples over the internet and they are valid. Errors can be related to the tooling or packages used in the old versions of add-ins, but the manifest and the way how the custom ribbon UI is built remains he same. Let me know what sample you are interested in and I'll consider creating and publishing it as a blog post.

Comment: The best way is to start with a new add-in and follow the guide mentioned to build a custom ribbon UI by the way.

Comment: If you do find the time, that would be awesome if you could make one. Just something that adds a custom tab to ribbon in Word, adds a menu in it and the menu makes a web api call. Nothing complex. Meantime,  I will try again with the standard code documentation above.

Comment: If you can't make it work I'll do that this weekend.

Comment: This link works for me @Eugene.https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/office-add-in-commands/word

Comment: Glad you have found the sample! Good luck with your project.